# Ecto query doesn't work on Absinthe resolution

Tags: elixir, ecto, absinthe

I'm trying to get working a simple query with [Absinthe#Batch](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Middleware.Batch.html), but the function where the Ecto query is being executed doesn't return any result.

I added some tracing to count the records on the db. **It is expected to return always 1, but doesn't**.

The Resolver:

```
def get_cards_for_stage(stage, _args, _ctx) do
  IO.puts "Before batch: #{OfferSid.Repo.aggregate(from(p in "pipeline_cards"), :count, :id)}"

  batch({__MODULE__, :pipeline_cards_by_stage_ids}, stage.id, fn batch_results ->

  IO.puts "Inside batch: #{OfferSid.Repo.aggregate(from(p in "pipeline_cards"), :count, :id)}"
    {:ok, Map.get(batch_results, stage.id)}
  end)
end
```

The Helper method:

```
def pipeline_cards_by_stage_ids(_args, stages_ids) do
  IO.puts "On the helper method: #{OfferSid.Repo.aggregate(Ecto.Query.from(p in "pipeline_cards"), :count, :id)}"

  cards = OfferSid.pipeline_cards_by_stage_ids(stages_ids)
  Map.new(cards, fn s -> {s.pipeline_stage_id, s} end)
end
```

Some tracing:

```
  # Before batch: 1
  # Before batch: 1
  # Before batch: 1
  # On the helper method: 0
  # Inside batch: 1
  # Inside batch: 1
  # Inside batch: 1
```

Comment: What does mean “does not work”? Fails? Throws an exception? How did you call it? What happens? Downvoted and voted to close the question until it’s clarified.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for your suggestions. I already improved the question.

Answer (score 1):

As [benwilson512](https://github.com/benwilson512) mentioned [here](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe/issues/484#issuecomment-356291629), the problem was the db connection wasn't [shared](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html#module-shared-mode).

So, I fixed it adding:

```
before do
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Repo, {:shared, self()})
end
```